# How can one lose reputation by posting a comment?

Tags: support, comments, reputation, delete

This is to report a curious effect. I just lost 2 reputation points (not that I care) and my indicator shows

[image]

The [linked post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403645/after-multicolumn-follow-line-is-strange) is a deleted question, and all I did was to add a comment there.

[image]

This is strange in two ways:

1. How can one lose reputation points through a comment?
2. How can one lose reputation points through a deleted post?

(I also know that minus times minus is plus, but I do not accept this as an explanation here. ;-)

Comment: back then, you suggested an edit that was accepted which earned you 2 points: https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/403645/revisions

Comment: @Troy Yes, that makes definitely more sense than minus times minus. So you are saying one can "earn" reputation through comments? (I am not implying that I disagree that I am certainly not aware of this.)

Comment: Not at all: just that you earned the 2 points from making the edit to the question back then, and when the question got deleted, it's (extremely likely that) the 2 point bonus in question was then taken away from you. nothing to do with the comment made at all :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You did more than leave a comment. You also suggested an edit to that question back in Nov 2017 (just >1 year ago):

[image: pic]

and notice the "edit approved" status. It suggests your reputation back then was not high enough to make [immediate edits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). It also means when your edit *was* approved, you earned a [2 point bonus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Now that the question has been deleted by the "community", it's just a matter of TeX.SE reversing that 2 point bonus you earned from that edit. Nothing to do with earning rep from comments whatsoever.